# Passing keys in an object and using it in *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, api, angular-material

I have an api response `[{"pass":15,"fail":80,"skip":5,"total":100}]` and want to show progress bar basis of pass, fail and skip values. These should be 3 bars.

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let summary of summaries" class="result-progress">
    <label for="">{{summary.label}}</label>
    <mat-progress-bar class="" [color]="summary.color"  [value]="summary.value"></mat-progress-bar>
    <span class="bar-tooltip" [ngStyle]="{'color': 'black'}">{{summary.value}}</span>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
   this.httpService.getResultProgress().subscribe((data) => {

      const res = data[0];
      const summaries = [];
      Object.keys(res).forEach((key)=>{
        summaries.push( {
          "label": key,
          "value": res[key],
          "color": "primary"

        })
        return summaries;
      })

      // chart.data = arr;
      console.log(summaries)

    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

here is console.log(summaries) result:

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {label: "pass", value: 15, color: "primary"}
1: {label: "fail", value: 80, color: "primary"}
2: {label: "skip", value: 5, color: "primary"}
3: {label: "total", value: 100, color: "primary"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I am not getting any error. Nothing is coming in html template. Don't know whats wrong.

expected result.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because, `summaries` is a local variable defined within `subscribe`. You need to make it a class member.

```js
export class MyComponent {
   summaries = []; // move it to the top

   ....
   this.httpService.getResultProgress().subscribe((data) => {

      const res = data[0];
      this.summaries = Object.keys(res).map(key=>{
        return {
          "label": key,
          "value": res[key],
          "color": "primary"

        };
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not storing the summaries in the component. Don't store the result of the data modification in a `const` inside the subscription, rather store it in a member of the component like this:

```
//In the class members
summaries = [];

this.httpService.getResultProgress().subscribe((data) => {

  const res = data[0];
  this.summaries = [];
  Object.keys(res).forEach((key) => {
    this.summaries.push( {
      "label": key,
      "value": res[key],
      "color": "primary"
    })
  });

  // chart.data = arr;
  console.log(summaries);

}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Also, returning something in the callback of `forEach` is useless so I removed         `return summaries;`

Answer (score 0):

Define `summaries` on the top (in constructor) as

```
this.summaries = []
```

and in the http call

```
this.summaries.push( {
          "label": key,
          "value": res[key],
          "color": "primary"

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML add async pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let summary of summaries | async" class="result-progress">
  <label for="">{{summary.label}}</label>
  <mat-progress-bar class="" [color]="summary.color"  [value]="summary.value"></mat-progress-bar>
  <span class="bar-tooltip" [ngStyle]="{'color': 'black'}">{{summary.value}}</span>
</div>
```

.ts map with rxjs response

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  summaries: Observable<Array<any>>;
  constructor(
    private httpService: HttpService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.summaries = this.httpService.getResultProgress().pipe(
      map(data => {
        const res = data[0];
        return Object.keys(res).map(key => {
          return {
            "label": key,
            "value": res[key],
            "color": "primary"
          };
        });
      })
    );
  }
}
```